# Spline 3D Integration issues with HTML Module on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have integrated my Spline design on my site (thevuittonclub.com). Rotating turntable and size is perfect on Safari.

On Chrome, the design's rotation is flipped, and is too small.
[Chrome Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6ErQ.png)

On Firefox, the design is enlarged too much.
[Firefox Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6glyV.png)

I currently use this html code to integrate it and adjust based on the user, but would appreciate any other workaround that is more universal (not just working for safari)

````
  function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = window.innerHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>

<iframe src="https://my.spline.design/untitled-737ba97ac2775e59939bc17dab8e9c00/" onload="resizeIframe(this);"
    ></iframe> ```
````